# Сложить элементы многомерного списка

Tags: c#

У меня есть многомерный список. Мне нужно сложить его элементы под индексом 4,5,6, а затем вывести пользователю

```
List<List<string>> Users = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string> {"******", "*", "*", "1.22.2002", "34", "24", "152"},
    new List<string> {"*****", "*", "*", "17.08.2004", "24", "2234", "1888"},
    new List<string> {"****", "*", "*", "3.1.2000", "24", "34", "352"},
    new List<string> {"*****", "****", "*", "4.7.1999", "224", "234", "1452"},
};
```

Последние 3 значения нужно сложить между собой и вывести. Как это сделать? Я нуб в c#

Comment: Для начала надо определиться, что именно складывать. Вот у вас список пользователей, я с трудом представляю, зачем и как складывать пароли или Id пользователей. И гм, в обычных приложениях так не делают: вам нужен `List<User>`, а не `List<List<string>>`  -иначе будет крайне неудобно работать.

Comment: @AK человек имеет ввиду 4,5,6 элементы под-списков, очевидно же

Comment: @AK Я так и указал. Мне нужно сложить 4, 5, 6 элементы этого списка. Просто скажите как мне их сложить и всё

Comment: Можете привести ожидаемый вывод?

Comment: Это у вас список списков. Многомерных списков в C# нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, если вы храните данные для обработки, лучше это делать в наиболее удобном формате. Строки надо хранить в `string`, дату в `DateTime`, целые числа - в `int`.

Вот к примеру, я создал класс `User`:

```cs
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string ThirdName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Number1 { get; set; }
    public int Number2 { get; set; }
    public int Number3 { get; set; }

    public User(string firstName, string secondName, string thirdName, DateTime date, int number1, int number2, int number3)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        SecondName = secondName;
        ThirdName = thirdName;
        Date = date;
        Number1 = number1;
        Number2 = number2;
        Number3 = number3;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", FirstName, SecondName, ThirdName, Date.ToString("D"), Number1, Number2, Number3);
    }
}
```

У него помимо необходимых свойств есть конструктор для удобного создания класса и переопределенный `ToString`, который я буду использовать для вывода данных в консоль.

И написал вот такой код:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<User> Users = new List<User>()
        {
            new User ("******", "*", "*", DateTime.Parse("22.1.2002"), 34, 24, 152),
            new User ("*****", "*", "*", DateTime.Parse("17.08.2004"), 24, 2234, 1888),
            new User ("****", "*", "*", DateTime.Parse("3.1.2000"), 24, 34, 352),
            new User ("*****", "****", "*", DateTime.Parse("4.7.1999"), 224, 234, 1452)
        };

        int result1 = 0, result2 = 0, result3 = 0;
        foreach (User data in Users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            result1 += data.Number1;
            result2 += data.Number2;
            result3 += data.Number3;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Результаты: {0}, {1}, {2}", result1, result2, result3);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

И получил вот такой вывод в консоль

```
******, *, *, 22 января 2002 г., 34, 24, 152
*****, *, *, 17 августа 2004 г., 24, 2234, 1888
****, *, *, 3 января 2000 г., 24, 34, 352
*****, ****, *, 4 июля 1999 г., 224, 234, 1452
Результаты: 306, 2526, 3844
```

Как видите, ничего сложного, если работать с правильно сохраненными данными.

Comment: Всё идеально. Спасибо!