# Как добавить элемент в многомерный список?

Tags: c#

Есть у меня такой код :

```
List<List<string>> Users = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                new List<string> {"*", "*", "*", "1.22.2002", "34", "24", "152"},
                new List<string> {"*", "*", "*", "17.08.2004", "24", "2234", "1888"},
                new List<string> {"*", "*", "*", "3.1.2000", "24", "34", "352"},
                new List<string> {"*", "*", "*", "4.7.1999", "224", "234", "1452"},
            };
```

Как я могу добавить в этот список значения, которые вводит пользователь?

Comment: _P.S. Я нуб в c#_ - [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Comment: Ну это ведь элементарно..  Users[0].Add(...); 0 - индекс нужного списка. Нужно что-то более существенное, тогда определяйтесь с тем, по каким параметрам идёт поиск нужного списка и делайте тогда нечто такое: Users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Contains(...)).Add(...); И вот вы уже добавляете в первый найденный список, содержащий то, что укажете. Но вообще, у вас очень плохая структура, в предыдущем вопросе вам показали как следует поступить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Окей, ошибку больше не выдает. Но когда я делаю вывод я не вижу тех данных, которые ввел

Comment: Не копируйте бездумно код, что вам дают, подумайте сами, почему такое может быть? Программирование - это логическое мышление.

Comment: А что не так с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1186275/373567)? Вот так добавить: `Users.Add(new User ("******", "*", "*", DateTime.Parse("22.1.2002"), 34, 24, 152))`

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал выделить отдельную сущность - User и определить там все необходимые поля. Если же задача работать именно с такой коллекцией, то добавление новых данных будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
var firstProperty = "*";
var secondProperty = "*";
var thirdProperty = "*";
var fourthProperty = "1.22.2002";
var fifthProperty = "34";
var sixthProperty = "24";
var seventhProperty = "152";

var user = new List<string> { firstProperty, secondProperty, thirdProperty, fourthProperty, fifthProperty, sixthProperty, seventhProperty };

Users.Add(user);
```

Первые 7 полей - это введённые пользователем данные, которые вы будете получать из нужных источников. Обращение к элементам общего списка будет реализовано следующим образом:

```
Users[0][0]
```

Где первый 0 - это порядковый номер вложенного списка, а второй 0 - порядковый номер нужного вам поля.

Comment: Ему уже написали это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1186262/213987